# How should I handle the creation and disposal of sessions using mgo.v2?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm connecting a golang webservice to a MongoDB database. I'm a little confused about what's the best and safest way of creating and storing the database sessions. In other languages I am used to an approach where I can open and close a connection for every request like (pseudocode)

```
conn = db.newConnection()
query = conn.query({id: 'my-id'})
conn.close()
```

which would ensure that the connection is always closed properly and resources are freed. Whenever there is a connectivity hiccup it will be affected only temporarily. Performance hits are not to be expected as databases are heavily optimized for such behavior.

Now, the [mgo docs on `Dial()`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Dial)(which is used for establishing a connection) state:

> This method is generally called just once for a given cluster. Further
>   sessions to the same cluster are then established using the New or
>   Copy methods on the obtained session. This will make them share the
>   underlying cluster, and manage the pool of connections appropriately.

which led to me having a single package level connection that I create on package `init` and which is then shared by all instantiated clients:

```
var database *mgo.Database
// Setup runs all the needed steps to establish a database connection
func Setup() error {
    var sessionErr error
    mongoSession, sessionErr = mgo.Dial(os.Getenv("MONGO_HOST"))
    if sessionErr != nil {
        return sessionErr
    }
    database = mongoSession.DB(os.Getenv("DB_NAME"))
    return nil
}
```

This works kind of ok, yet I am running into issues where about once a month the connection to the database is lost and cannot be recovered during the lifetime of the process (making all requests return `EOF` and requiring someone to restart the process). I have never seen this happen using the connect-and-close-on-each-query approach I have described above.

I'm pretty sure I must be doing something wrong, but I feel I am doing what the docs tell me and all examples I can find on the web are one-off things that do not cover the case of a long-running application.

What is the recommended way of handling Mongo connections in a failure safe way inside long-running applications using `mgo`? Is there an established pattern of using [`Copy()`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.Copy) or [`New()`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Session.New) which are mentioned in the documentation? Will using them prevent permanently failed connections?

Comment: Check at this stack as some of your issues are addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574594/best-practice-to-maintain-a-mgo-session

Comment: @reticentroot cool thanks for digging that up, somehow wasn't able to find it.