# Golang mgo store Session or Collection

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

When my server starts up, it will create a connection to a mongo database, grab that `*mgo.Session` and store it in a "server" struct for handlers defined on that struct to use to serve requests.

I see two ways to actually execute this.

```
1) Save the `*mgo.Session` in the struct.
```

The upside of this is that you can call `Session.Copy` in each handler before using the session to have connection isolation. The downside is that you need to call `.DB("x").C("y")` for a specific `x` and `y` for each handler. If you wanted to change this, you need to find each instance where you're using it and change it. That's less than ideal.

```
2) Store the `*mgo.Database` or even `*mgo.Collection` object on the server struct.
```

The upside is that you can configure it in one place and use it. The downside is that there appears to be no way to use `Copy()` on the thing for connection isolation.

How do you recommend storing the mongo session so that you can cleanly use the connection and provide isolation between requests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice to maintain a mgo session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26576589/3508174).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice to maintain a mgo session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26574594/best-practice-to-maintain-a-mgo-session)